# Несколько string условий if

Tags: python, if

Привет!
У меня несколько  условий для if, условия эти - строки, написанные в кавычках. Определенные строки нужно найти в длинном списке и вытащить их, напечатать с помощью print. 
Перечисляя строки с помощью and в if у меня не выходит, я создал функцию check, но и с ней получается напечатать только единственную строку, а нужно 2, как в этом примере, или больше.

```
def binance():
..
def main():
    check = all('BCC' and 'LTC')
    bin = bina()
    for i in (bin):
        if check in i['symbol']:
            print (i ['symbol'])
```

Comment: Не знаю как Вы, но лично я ничего не понял :)

Comment: вы можете привести пример данных которые проверяете и то что хотите получить на выходе. В такой формулировке вопрос - непонятный...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
def main():
    check = ['BCC', 'LTC']
    bin = bina()
    for i in (bin):
        for j in check:
            if j in i['symbol']:
                print(i ['symbol'])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Два цикла создать я не догадался..

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями (чтобы искать в одном цикле), если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
import re

texts = ['a string BCC ...', 'another string LTC', 'IGNORE ME']
check = ['BCC', 'LTC']

pat = '|'.join(check)
res = [x for x in texts if re.search(pat, x)]
```

Результат:

```
In [89]: res
Out[89]: ['a string BCC ...', 'another string LTC']
```